# Getting redundancy in xslt output and How to get exact sequence of elements in xslt output as Input

Tags: java, xslt

I am new to XSLT. I am transforming an XML document to XHTML format. In my XSLT output I am getting Redundancy and not getting exact sequence of elements in output as input.

My Input:

```
<TLV1 ID="B01429413.0-7">
  <P>All rights reserved.</P>
  <P>
    <E T="I">Production Services:</E>Aptara, Inc.
  </P>
  <LK>ABCD !!!!!!</LK>
  <P>
    <E T="I">ACSM's Publications Committee Chair:</E>Jeffrey L.
    Roitman, EdD, FACSM
  </P>
  <P>
    <E T="I">ACSM Group Publisher:</E>D. Mark Robertson
  </P>
  <LK>WXYZ !!!!!!</LK>
  <P>&#160;&#160;&#160;p. cm.</P>
  <P>
    To purchase additional copies of this book, call our customer
    service department at
    <E T="B">(301) 223-2320</E>. International customers should call.
  </P>
  <P>
    <E T="BIT">
      Visit Lippincott Williams &amp; Wilkins on the
      Internet: http://www.lww.com.
    </E>Lippincott Williams &amp;
    Wilkins customer service representatives are available from 8:30
    am to 6:00 pm, EST.
  </P>
</TLV1>
```

My Applied XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
  indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//TLV1"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="TLV1">
    <div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">TLV1</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:if test="P">
        <xsl:for-each select="P">
          <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">P</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]" />
            <xsl:if test="E">
              <xsl:for-each select="E">
                <span>
                  <xsl:attribute name="class">emph_I</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:apply-templates />
                </span>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]" />
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="LK">
          <xsl:for-each select="LK">
            <xsl:value-of select="LK"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply this xslt to input so all "P" Elements process first then "LK" so I am losing order in output. And also get redundancy in "div" and "span" element.

My Output:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="TLV1">
  <div class="P">All rights reserved.</div>
  <div class="P">
    Production Services:<span class="emph_I">Production Services:</span>Aptara, Inc.
  </div>
  <div class="P">
    ACSM's Publications Committee Chair:<span class="emph_I">ACSM's Publications Committee Chair:</span>Jeffrey L.
    Roitman, EdD, FACSM
  </div>
  <div class="P">
    ACSM Group Publisher:<span class="emph_I">ACSM Group Publisher:</span>D. Mark Robertson
  </div>
  <div class="P">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;p. cm.</div>
  <div class="P">
    To purchase additional copies of this book, call our customer
    service department at
    <span class="emph_I">(301) 223-2320</span>. International customers should call.
  </div>
  <div class="P">
    Visit Lippincott Williams &amp; Wilkins on the
    Internet: http://www.lww.com.<span class="emph_I">
      Visit Lippincott Williams &amp; Wilkins on the
      Internet: http://www.lww.com.
    </span>Lippincott Williams &amp;
    Wilkins customer service representatives are available from 8:30
    am to 6:00 pm, EST.
  </div>
  <div class="LK">
    ABCD !!!!!!
  </div>
  <div class="LK">
    WXYZ !!!!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

All "P" Elements processed first after that "LK" Processed.  And ACSM Group Publisher: got 2 times in "div" and then "span".

Expected Output: I want this output..

```
<div class="TLV1">
  <div class="P">All rights reserved.</div>
  <div class="P">
    <span class="emph_I">Production Services:</span>Aptara,Inc.
  </div>
  <div class="LK">
    ABCD !!!!!!
  </div>
  <div class="P">
    <span class="emph_I">
      ACSM's Publications Committee
      Chair:
    </span>Jeffrey L. Roitman, EdD, FACSM
  </div>
  <div class="P">
    <span class="emph_I">ACSM Group Publisher:</span>D. Mark Robertson
  </div>
  <div class="LK">
    WXYZ !!!!!!
  </div>
  <div class="P">&#160;&#160;&#160;p. cm.</div>
  <div class="P">
    To purchase additional copies of this book, call
    our customer service department at
    <span class="emph_B">(301) 223-2320</span>. International
    customers should call.
  </div>
  <div class="P">
    <span class="emph_BIT">
      Visit Lippincott Williams &amp; Wilkins on
      the Internet:
      <a href="http://www.lww.com">
        http://www.lww.com
      </a>.
    </span>Lippincott Williams &amp; Wilkins
    customer service representatives are available from 8:30 am to
    6:00 pm, EST.
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for long the post !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to let the templates do the work for you here, and not a bunch of `if`s and `for-each`es:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//TLV1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TLV1 | P | LK">
    <div class="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="E">
    <span class="emph_I">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<div class="TLV1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <div class="P">All rights reserved.</div>
  <div class="P">
    <span class="emph_I">Production Services:</span>Aptara, Inc.
  </div>
  <div class="LK">ABCD !!!!!!</div>
  <div class="P">
    <span class="emph_I">ACSM's Publications Committee Chair:</span>Jeffrey L.
    Roitman, EdD, FACSM
  </div>
  <div class="P">
    <span class="emph_I">ACSM Group Publisher:</span>D. Mark Robertson
  </div>
  <div class="LK">WXYZ !!!!!!</div>
  <div class="P">   p. cm.</div>
  <div class="P">
    To purchase additional copies of this book, call our customer
    service department at
    <span class="emph_I">(301) 223-2320</span>. International customers should call.
  </div>
  <div class="P">
    <span class="emph_I">
      Visit Lippincott Williams &amp; Wilkins on the
      Internet: http://www.lww.com.
    </span>Lippincott Williams &amp;
    Wilkins customer service representatives are available from 8:30
    am to 6:00 pm, EST.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your control flow seems needlessly convoluted here. In most cases the better approach is to start with the Identity Transform, add templates for each of the cases you want to process, and recursively call `<xsl:apply-templates>` to select each of the current node's children and style it (and its contents) in turn. Write rules -- general and exceptions -- rather than procedures, whenever possible.

Also, you really should take more advantage of literal result attributes, when you don't need to compute an attribute's value.

If I'm reading your code correctly, what you wanted is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TLV1">
    <div class="TLV1">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="P">
    <div class="P">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LK">
    <div class="LK">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="E">
    <span class="emph_I"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```